# Google Maps - Moving marker to location based on map div size?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Say I have a map div:

```
____________________
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|             m     |
|                   |
|                   |
|   x               |
|___________________|
```

m is where the marker is now (actually I don't really care where the marker is initially).  I want to move the marker 5% div height, 8% div width from the bottom left corner to the x location (moving by pixels is okay too).  Given that the map size can be of any size, how would I go about moving a marker from m to location x in the map.

Note: Just to clarify, I don't want the location(lat, lng) of the marker to change, but rather move the map such that the marker moves in the map div to location x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I put together something workable for close-up zooms (around 9 or higher). You will notice quickly at world-view zooms that it is horribly broken when the marker is near the poles or the International Date Line is visible on the map.

Well, it's a starting point. http://jsfiddle.net/TQ8YY/1/

Drag the marker to your area of interest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do something like this

Comment: It really depends on your application, test a lot or upgrade the code I wrote. Good luck!

Comment: I saw something relevant on another question, you can compute lengths directly in pixels, so you'd get same results no matter where you are on the globe. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection the method is fromContainerPixelToLatLng(pixel:Point)